# Determining source of QGIS Action

Tags: pyqgis, actions

I'm new to QGIS, using v 3.18.  I would like to write an action that is triggered when a user inserts a point on a layer.  For example.  I have a point layer named `testLayer`.  In the properties dialog, there is an action list.  If I select the + button to add an action, I can define some python that can be applied to the actions scopes.  If the user is inserting a point, the action will be called.  How do I get the feature that is being added to the layer?  Specifically on the `testLayer`, there is an attribute called `NodeId`.  I would like to:

1. Grab the feature
2. Get the row number
3. Create the `NodeId` (similar to using the expression with `lpad("id",3, '0')`)
4. Use the feature to get a `QgsPointXY` for the point
5. Create a line on another layer that has a `fromNode` and `toNode` column based on the `NodeId` and `QgsPointXY`

I can't do any of that without knowing which feature is being added to the layer.

Answer (score 5):

`QgsVectorLayer` class has `featureAdded` signal. First, you need to connect it to a new method which has one parameter (`feature_id` here) which grabs the newly added feature id.
In edit mode, this id is a negative value.

I have no experience on "Actions" in "Layer Properties", but you can get the feature (`QgsFeature` object) that is being added to the layer using the following script.

```py
def feature_added(feature_id):
    print(feature_id)
    new_feature = layer.getFeature(feature_id)
    pointXY = new_feature.geometry().asPoint() # returns QgsPointXY
    print(pointXY)

layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.featureAdded.connect(feature_added)
```